# Is it a security risk to be using Doctrine1 today, as the PHP Library has not been updated in 8 years?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

We have an application that is running Doctrine1 and it would be a VERY large undertaking to upgrade from Doctrine1 to the current Doctrine3 (essentially a complete rewrite).

From a security standpoint, what is the risk with using this library?

We have updated to PHP7 and all the latest MySQL, and are now looking at libraries.

Comment: google: Doctrine 1 cve